# Casting into grouping row

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ado.net

I dont know why i am getting the following exception how can I cast into grouping Row ? What does grouping row means

[image]

Comment: I'm surprised that even compiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InvoiceHeaderCollection` is a collection of groups, the groups is something like:

```
      Key               Value
 invoice account1      datarow1 //the value is a `DataRow`
                       datarow2
                       datarow4
 invoice account2      datarow3
 invoice account3      datarow5
```

So I think you need:

```
foreach(var g in InvoiceHeaderCollection)
{
    DataRow[] rows = g.ToArray();   //to get all the DataRows in the group
    //maybe another loop through the rows
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: change the code to

```
foreach(var InvoiceHeader in InvoiceHeadercollection)
```

The linq code has generated a new class, which you can think of like this:

```
class AutoGeneratedClass :  IEnumerable<DataRow>
{
    public string Key { get; }  // The InvoiceAccount field
}
```

(It's not called "AutoGeneratedClass"; I'm just using that so it follows the syntax we know). Because there's no name for this automatically generated class, you have to use "var".

Comment: then i will I get the on Field<string>(..)

Answer (score 1):

Look at your LINQ query, you are using `group by`  - `InvoiceHeaderCollection` is **not** a collection of data rows, it's an `IGrouping<DataRow>`, a different group for each different "Invoice account".
 - what did you want to do with the grouping? Or did you intend to *order* your rows by Invoice account?